# Flutter won't build appbundle after update to android 3.5.0

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

The thing is that I try to build a appbundle for a flutter app but it crashes i search for results about the errors but found nothing hope some one could help.

NOTE : The app launch and works perfectly on both IOS and Android but doesn't build on any of them I'll make a post for the Ios problem and I'll link it here when it will be done. "link"

You can find below the result of my "flutter doctor -v" and "flutter build appbundle -v".

**flutter doctor -v :**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A602, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at /Users/axel/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aedbb1835 (4 days ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/axel/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 10
      (API 29) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro             • DB06E423-957F-41AA-99D0-05735D90C30B • ios         •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

**flutter build appbundle -v :**

```
[  +25 ms] executing: [/Users/axel/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +41 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 1aedbb1835bd6eb44550293d57d4d124f19901f0
[        ] executing: [/Users/axel/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long
--tags
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.9.1+hotfix.5-0-g1aedbb183
[   +8 ms] executing: [/Users/axel/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +11 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/Users/axel/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +62 ms] executing: [/Users/axel/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +80 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[ +106 ms] Found plugin contacts_service at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/contacts_service-0.2.9/
[  +21 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+8/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin firebase_messaging at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.3/
[   +8 ms] Found plugin flutter_crashlytics at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_crashlytics-1.0.0/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin flutter_email_sender at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_email_sender-2.0.3/
[  +15 ms] Found plugin flutter_secure_storage at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-3.2.1+1/
[   +9 ms] Found plugin flutter_worldpay at /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter_worldpay/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin geolocator at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-5.1.1+1/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin google_api_availability at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_api_availability-2.0.1/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/
[  +11 ms] Found plugin image_picker at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.1/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin keyboard_visibility at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/keyboard_visibility-0.5.6/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin local_auth at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.4.0+1/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin location_permissions at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-2.0.2/
[   +8 ms] Found plugin native_device_orientation at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/native_device_orientation-0.1.2/
[   +5 ms] Found plugin path_provider at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-0.5.0+1/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin permission_handler at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-3.2.1+1/
[  +10 ms] Found plugin qr_mobile_vision at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/
[   +7 ms] Found plugin share_extend at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share_extend-1.0.9/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.3+4/
[   +5 ms] Found plugin sqflite at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.1.6+3/
[  +10 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.2.3/
[  +47 ms] Found plugin contacts_service at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/contacts_service-0.2.9/
[   +6 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+8/
[        ] Found plugin firebase_messaging at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.3/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin flutter_crashlytics at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_crashlytics-1.0.0/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin flutter_email_sender at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_email_sender-2.0.3/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin flutter_secure_storage at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-3.2.1+1/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin flutter_worldpay at /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter_worldpay/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin geolocator at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-5.1.1+1/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin google_api_availability at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_api_availability-2.0.1/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.20+1/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin image_picker at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.1/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin keyboard_visibility at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/keyboard_visibility-0.5.6/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin local_auth at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-0.4.0+1/
[   +1 ms] Found plugin location_permissions at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_permissions-2.0.2/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin native_device_orientation at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/native_device_orientation-0.1.2/
[   +5 ms] Found plugin path_provider at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-0.5.0+1/
[   +2 ms] Found plugin permission_handler at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-3.2.1+1/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin qr_mobile_vision at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/
[   +6 ms] Found plugin share_extend at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share_extend-1.0.9/
[   +4 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.3+4/
[   +3 ms] Found plugin sqflite at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.1.6+3/
[  +11 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at
/Users/axel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.2.3/
[ +320 ms] Initializing gradle...
[   +5 ms] Using gradle from /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradlew.
[ +158 ms] executing: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
[        ] {"CFBundleName":"Android
Studio","JVMOptions":{"ClassPath":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/bootstrap.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents
\/lib\/extensions.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/util.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/jdom.jar:$A
PP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/log4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/trove4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents
\/lib\/jna.jar","JVMVersion":"1.8*,1.8+","WorkingDirectory":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/bin","MainClass
":"com.intellij.idea.Main","Properties":{"idea.paths.selector":"AndroidStudio3.5","idea.executable":
"studio","idea.platform.prefix":"AndroidStudio","idea.home.path":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents"}},"LSArchi
tecturePriority":["x86_64"],"CFBundleVersion":"AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
":"English","CFBundleDocumentTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeName":"Android Studio Project
File","CFBundleTypeExtensions":["ipr"],"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleTypeIconFile":"studio.ic
ns"},{"CFBundleTypeName":"All
documents","CFBundleTypeExtensions":["*"],"CFBundleTypeOSTypes":["****"],"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor"
,"LSTypeIsPackage":false}],"NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching":true,"CFBundlePackageType":"APPL",
"CFBundleIconFile":"studio.icns","NSHighResolutionCapable":true,"CFBundleShortVersionString":"3.5","
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","CFBundleExecutable":"studio","LSRequiresNativeExecution":"YES"
,"CFBundleURLTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleURLName":"Stacktrace","CFBundleURLSchemes
":["idea"]}],"CFBundleIdentifier":"com.google.android.studio","LSApplicationCategoryType":"public.ap
p-category.developer-tools","CFBundleSignature":"????","LSMinimumSystemVersion":"10.8","CFBundleGetI
nfoString":"Android Studio 3.5, build AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203. Copyright JetBrains s.r.o., (c)
2000-2019"}
[  +99 ms] executing: /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradlew -v
[ +766 ms] 
                    ------------------------------------------------------------
                    Gradle 4.10.2
                    ------------------------------------------------------------

                    Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
                    Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

                    Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
                    Kotlin:       1.2.61
                    Groovy:       2.4.15
                    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
                    JVM:          1.8.0_202-release (JetBrains s.r.o 25.202-b49-5587405)
                    OS:           Mac OS X 10.15 x86_64
[  +10 ms] Initializing gradle... (completed in 1.0s)
[  +11 ms] Resolving dependencies...
[        ] executing: [/Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/]
/Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradlew app:properties
[ +685 ms] 
                    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

                    * Where:
                    Build file '/Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/app/build.gradle'
                    line: 34

                    * What went wrong:
                    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
                    > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
                       > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If
                       using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
                       /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.p
                       roperties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

                    * Try:
                    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
                    option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

                    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

                    BUILD FAILED in 0s
[   +6 ms] Resolving dependencies... (completed in 0.7s)
[   +4 ms] * Error running Gradle:
           ProcessException: Process "/Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradlew" exited
abnormally:

           FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

           * Where:
           Build file '/Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 34

           * What went wrong:
           A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
           > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
              > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the
gradle
              wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
              /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
to
              gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

           * Try:
           Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more
           log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

           * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

           BUILD FAILED in 0s
             Command: /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradlew app:properties

[   +4 ms] "flutter appbundle" took 2,579ms.
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _readGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:233:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _gradleAppProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:112:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:652:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:494:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      buildAppBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/app_bundle.dart:43:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_appbundle.dart:47:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
#8      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#11     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#12     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#14     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#15     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#18     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#19     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#20     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#21     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#22     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#23     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so the problem i had was that the minimum sdk supported was 21 and above when I was at 18.

So the solution is to change minSDKVersion :

```
minSdkVersion 18
```

to

```
 minSdkVersion 22
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there in the log

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. 
If using wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
          /Users/axel/Documents/CSC/flutter-app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Upgrade your gradle version to 5.4.1